# Netlogo - Controlling specific sets of turtles

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to develop a model to demonstrate a field principle I am trying to work with. I am having trouble finding information on how to control specific groups of turtles. Essentially I would like to make a grid of turtles and links that I can distort, relative to an objective coordinate grid, based upon the placement of a different type of turtle, like a particle interacting with a field?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Is it possible to write a command that only talks to specific turtles by their who value? for instance if i had a coordinate plane that went from -3,3 in both x and y, rendering 49 vertices, could I set up those first 49 turtles, and then spawn my particle turtles (lets say 3), which would be who 49,50, and 51. could I write a command specifically for those 3 turtles based upon their relations to the first 49 turtles?

I hope this question makes sense.

Comment: Using `who` numbers is seldom appropriate.  Is there any reason not to use breeds?

Comment: I guess i misunderstood that command. So that essentially defines different groups of turtles that you can command independently?

Comment: Yeah this completely resolved my issue, but brought me immediately into a new issue. I want to spawn a certain number of 1 breed and place each of them at a different vertex, would I have to write a unique spawn code for each of those as they need to be placed specifically, or can i write a loop or something to place them?

Comment: Do not use the comments section to ask completely new questions.  :-)